# Проблема установки Bootstrap4

Tags: python, django

Ошибка:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный
>   путь: 'C:\python_work\learning_log\static'

Работаю с джанго, пытаюсь начать изучать bootstrap, в каком-то месте ошибочно прописан поиск статичных файлов, и добаляется еще один слеш, в итоге я не могу подключить к html документу библиотеку со стилями, ибо статичные файлы не находятся. Так я прописал путь. Сама же директория вот такая: `C:\python_work\learning_log\learning_log\static\css`

```
</head>
      {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
      <body>
        <!-- Статическая навигационная панель -->
        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="conteiner">

            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">
                Learning Log</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали, какая именно папка является корневой для проекта, поэтому точно сказать не могу.
Попробуйте проверить следующее:

1. Ваше приложение в INSTALLED_APPS;
2. Правильно указаны STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT;
3. В шаблон добавлен {% load static %};
4. Правильно указан путь.

Вот рабочий пример:

***settings.py:***

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myapp'
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

***index.html:***

```html
{% load static %}
...
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/myapp/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
...
```

`bootstrap.min.css` находится по пути:

```html
Project_root/myapp/static/myapp/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Приведите структуру проекта, и я детализирую ответ под Вас.